# Can't presentModalView on viewWillAppear in a UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I actually work on an iPad application, which contains a secured member area.
The application itself uses a TabBarNavigation with a UIViewController for each tab.

To show up the LoginForm on the "Member-Area"-Tab, when User is not logged in, I created the LoginScreen in a separate UIViewController and tried to present it as ModalView on the ViewWillAppear-Method.

Unlikely it seems that ViewWillAppear / ViewDidLoad can't handle the modal view.
Every Tutorial or Sample I found uses a Button-Action to show up the ModalView.

Isn't it possible to show it without pressing something?

The Code I used in "MemberViewController" ViewWillAppear looks like that:

```
        -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    LoginViewController *loginInstance = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    [self presentModalViewController:loginInstance animated:YES];    
    [loginInstance release];
}
```

Would be great if someone could help!

Comment: be careful, you are releasing `loginInstance`, which you already autoreleased two lines above

Comment: uh, thanks. I added the autorelease later and forget to delete the release at the bottom. ;) But this will still not solve my problem =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an empty UIViewController, with something like this:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "MemberViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self performSelector:@selector(checkForLogin)];
}

- (void)checkForLogin {
NSString * checkString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LoginCheck"];

if ([checkString isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {

MemberViewController * memberInstance = [[MemberViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:memberInstance animated:YES];
[memberInstance release];

} else {

LoginViewController * loginInstance = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:loginInstance animated:YES];
[loginInstance release];

}

}
```

In the LoginViewController.h add this to the function that's being called when the login is valid:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"LoginCheck"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I think this should do the trick ;-)

There can be some errors, I typed this from my head right here on the website

Edit: attach the new empty view controller to the UITabBarController item where the login is needed ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot, your way seems to work! Only problem is to update the ViewController that switches the views wenn UserDefaults get changed. I change "LoginCheck" to "YES" if the Login is successful and to "NO" if the User clicks the Logout Button in the Member Area. But the switch only works if I restart the app, or change View. How can I reload the View to change the Modal when Status changes?

Comment: I see you figured it out :) Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 4):

You can't present the modal before your view has appeared, so you'll have to do it in viewDidAppear. I bet you don't want to show what's behind the modal though. Your best bet is to just hide everything in the main view until the user has authenticated in your modal. You can place the code to reveal everything, so that it's there when the modal animates away, in the same method that call dismissModalViewController.

Quick tip: if you have a bunch of stuff you need to hide/reveal and you don't want to hide each and every one manually, just throw them all in a container view and hide/reveal that one view.

Comment: hey, thanks for the tip. I tried to do it in viewDidAppear, but the ModalView still don't show up. =/

Comment: I tried to do this in viewDidAppear and it worked very well for me. Have my upvote

Answer (score 1):

It works, hell yeah! ;D

The only thing I have added to Rick's example was a dismiss of the current Modal, to reload the View.

Here the complete solution:

I created an empty UIViewController with Nib to switch between the LoginView and the MemberView:

```
    #import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "MemberViewController.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self performSelector:@selector(checkForLogin)];
}

- (void)checkForLogin {
NSString * checkString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"LoginCheck"];

if ([checkString isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {

MemberViewController * memberInstance = [[MemberViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:memberInstance animated:YES];
[memberInstance release];

} else {

LoginViewController * loginInstance = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:loginInstance animated:YES];
[loginInstance release];

}

}
```

Then I added this code to the method where UserLogin is successful:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"LoginCheck"];
```

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

and at least I use this at the end of this method to refresh the Controller that switches the Modals:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Thanks for your great support guys,  especially thanks to you Rick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this addresses your problem directly, but try presenting the modal in `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` instead of viewWillAppear. viewWillAppear gets run before the animated change of view, and I'm pretty sure you want the login to pop up after MemberViewController is in view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it with viewDidAppear instead, but the problem is still the same. If I build and run the App, the Member-Area-Tab still show the Main View, without the LoginView as ModalView. =/

Comment: Are viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear getting called?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into a funny situation where animating a modal view controller in the same run loop as the view appearing, causes everything to go awry.  It sounds like you are trying to have the LoginViewController showing when the user first enters the member area. Try displaying the modal non-animated

[self presentModalViewController:loginInstance animated:NO];

If you want to get funny with it, try this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(_showModal) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0f];
}

-(void)_showModal 
{
    LoginViewController *loginInstance = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    [self presentModalViewController:loginInstance animated:YES];    
}
```

Edit: On second glance, you also forgot to call super in your viewWillAppear method - which is required, and might be causing your issue.

Comment: hey, I tried it with your snippet. Still no result. The Modal don't show up. =/